# Can a redirect be setup for a PDF file’s web address?

Tags: html, file, redirect

The location of a PDF file has been moved to another folder on our GoDaddy website server.  A web address link to the PDF file is on the website’s landing page.  I’ve been asked if an automatic redirect to the file’s new location can be set up at the file’s original location.  The person does not want to change a bookmark they have set up that points to the file's original location (yes, I know this sounds lazy).

I know URL page redirects are possible but I don’t think something similar is possible for a link to a file.

I have not been able to find any way to set up a file redirect as described above.

Comment: On your server this is totally possible. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections for details. How to execute it will depend on your server setup.